# Making a Talking Application with Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a Talking Application (Text to speech) with Visual Basic 2008, but I can't.
Because, I am new in Visual Basic.
Please help me friends

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to ask questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In Vbscript you can do something like that :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Voice,input
Set Voice = WScript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Input = InputBox("Enter the text for this computer can try to pronounce it.","Make Talking Computer By Hackoo","Hello! How are you ?") 
Voice.speak "Today is " & date
Voice.speak Input
```

Comment: tnx, I will try this code.